# Asana API methods for changing user's Asana configuration

Tags: asana, asana-api

For each of our users (and new users we onboard) we'd like to:

- automatically save a pre-defined custom search
- automate adding certain projects to "My Dashboard"

In my research, the APIs appear to primarily revolve around leveraging Asana as a data source instead of allowing for the mutation of a user's actual Asana experience.

Anyone have any ideas for how we would go about doing either of these? We've considered building a browser extension to fire the requests, but would rather have an API-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we don't support this in our API. This might come in the future, but almost certainly not within the next six months. Sorry!

Our web app's sync protocol is pretty complex, so I don't expect you to be able to figure out how to fire in-browser requests.